# 1:1 Relationship for Results/Date in range

Tags: sql, sql-server, resultset

I am trying to get my query to output a row of performance results for each day in the range I am pulling.  I keep getting about 10 rows per rep, per day with strange looking results.  Would you be able to verify how I can alter my query to break down the results to a day by day reading?  Sorry for the trouble...let me know if I should word this differently.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS SMALLDATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2012-04-01'
SET @EndDate = '2012-04-30'

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SELECT
      DT.DateFull,
      --DATEPART(MM,DT.DateFull) AS Date,
      --DATENAME(MM,DT.DateFull) AS [Month],  
      E.AreaID,      
      --E.GeographicLocationID,      
      E.EmployeeID,
      ES.PeopleSoftTitleStartDate,
      QA.TopRep,
      QA.RepCount,
      CASE 
          WHEN SUM(QA.TopRep) = '0' OR SUM(RepCount) = '0'
          THEN '0'
          ELSE CAST(100*(SUM(QA.TopRep))/SUM(QA.RepCount) AS DECIMAL (8,2))
      END 'ERP',  
      QA.RepResolve,
      QA.RepResolveCount,
      CASE 
          WHEN SUM(QA.RepResolve) = '0' OR SUM(RepResolveCount) = '0'
          THEN '0'
          ELSE CAST(100*(SUM(QA.RepResolve))/SUM(QA.RepResolveCount) AS DECIMAL (8,2))
      END 'RR',
      QA.ACSNPSPromoter,
      QA.ACSNPSDetractor,
      QA.ACSNPSCount,
      CASE
          WHEN QA.ACSNPSCount = '0'
          THEN '0'
          ELSE CAST(100*(SUM(QA.ACSNPSPromoter)-SUM(QA.ACSNPSDetractor))/SUM(QA.ACSNPSCount) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
      END 'NPS',
      AHT.AHT,
      AHT.TalkTime,
      AHT.CallWorkTime,
      AHT.HandledCalls/*,
      CASE  
        WHEN (DT.DateFull Between emp.Transition_Date and emp.Month_one) 
        THEN 'First 30 Days'
        WHEN (DT.DateFull Between emp.Month_one And emp.Month_Two ) 
        THEN '30 - 60 days'
        WHEN (DT.DateFull Between emp.Month_Two And emp.Month_Three) 
        THEN '60-90 days'
        ELSE 'After Period'
      END AS Stat_Period*/

INTO #DATA              

FROM 
    dbTools.Config.vwDate AS DT WITH(NOLOCK)     

INNER JOIN 
     dbEmployee.Summary.vwEmployeeHistory AS E WITH(NOLOCK)          

ON 
    DT.datefull BETWEEN E.StartDate AND E.EndDate

LEFT JOIN
    dbEmployee.Summary.vwEmployeeSnapshot AS ES WITH(NOLOCK)
ON
    E.EmployeeID = ES.EmployeeID
    AND DT.datefull BETWEEN E.StartDate AND E.EndDate

LEFT JOIN
--ERP and Rep Resolve
(SELECT
    MONTH(StatDate) AS Mth,
    EmployeeID,
    --SUM(ACSTopRepScore)/SUM(ACSEntireRepCount) AS ERP,
    ACSTopRepScore AS TopRep,
    ACSEntireRepCount AS RepCount,
    --SUM(ACSRepResolvedScore)/SUM(ACSRepResolvedCount) AS RepResolve,
    ACSRepResolvedScore AS RepResolve,
    ACSRepResolvedCount AS RepResolveCount,
    ACSNPSPromoter AS ACSNPSPromoter,
    ACSNPSDetractor AS ACSNPSDetractor,
    ACSNPSCount AS ACSNPSCount

FROM
    dbReportSummary.ReportSummary.vwAfterCallSurvey WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE
    StatDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

GROUP BY
    MONTH(StatDate),
    EmployeeID,
    ACSTopRepScore,
    ACSEntireRepCount, 
    ACSRepResolvedScore, 
    ACSRepResolvedCount,
    ACSNPSPromoter, 
    ACSNPSDetractor,
    ACSNPSCount



) AS QA

ON
    (QA.Mth IN (MONTH(DT.DateFull)))
    AND QA.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID

LEFT JOIN
--AHT--
(SELECT 
    MONTH(StatDate) AS Mth,
    EmployeeId,
    HandledCalls AS HandledCalls,
    TalkTime AS TalkTime,
    CallWorkTime AS CallWorkTime,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(TalkTime) + SUM(CallWorkTime) = 0 OR SUM(HandledCalls) = 0
        THEN 0.0
            ELSE (SUM(TalkTime) + SUM(CallWorkTIme))/SUM(HandledCalls)
        END 'AHT'

FROM
    dbReportSummary.ReportSummary.vwACDAgentSummary WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE
    StatDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

GROUP BY
    MONTH(StatDate),
    EmployeeId,
    HandledCalls, 
    TalkTime,
    CallWorkTime

) AS AHT

ON
    (AHT.Mth IN (MONTH(DT.DateFull)))
    AND AHT.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID

WHERE
    (DT.DateFull <=@EndDate AND DT.DateFull >=@StartDate)
    AND (E.StartDate <=@EndDate AND E.EndDate >=@StartDate)
    AND (E.PeopleSoftDepartmentFunctionID = 'CSC')
    AND E.PeopleSoftDepartmentID IN ('9030', '9080', '9355', '9040', '<<OSCCALTECH>>', '<<WDTSMO>>', '9195','<<OSVTS>>', '<<OSVTS_TCS>>','9085')
    AND E.EmployeeID IS NOT NULL
    AND (ES.PeopleSoftTitleStartDate BETWEEN DT.DateFull AND DT.DateFull + 90)

GROUP BY
        DT.DateFull,
      --DATEPART(MM,DT.DateFull),
      --DATENAME(MM,DT.DateFull), 
      E.AreaID,                                
     -- E.GeographicLocationID,       
      E.EmployeeID,
      ES.PeopleSoftTitleStartDate,
      QA.TopRep,
      QA.RepCount,
      QA.RepResolve,
      QA.RepResolveCount,
      QA.ACSNPSPromoter,
      QA.ACSNPSDetractor,
      QA.ACSNPSCount,
      AHT.AHT,
      AHT.TalkTime,
      AHT.CallWorkTime,
      AHT.HandledCalls         

SELECT
    D.DateFull,
    --Date,
    --[Month],
    D.AreaID,
    --GE.GeographicLocationDescription AS Center,           
    D.EmployeeID,
    nE.EmployeeName,
    D.PeopleSoftTitleStartDate,     
    D.TopRep,
    D.RepCount,
    D.ERP,
    D.RepResolve,
    D.RepResolveCount,
    D.RR,
    D.ACSNPSPromoter,
    D.ACSNPSDetractor,
    D.ACSNPSCount,
    D.NPS,
    D.AHT,
    D.TalkTime,
    D.CallWorkTime,
    D.HandledCalls

FROM #DATA AS D                                                        

LEFT JOIN 
    dbEmployee.Config.vwName AS nE WITH (NOLOCK)   
ON
    D.EmployeeID = nE.EmployeeID

--LEFT JOIN 
--  dbEmployee.Config.vwGeographicLocation AS GE WITH (NOLOCK)               
--ON 
--  GE.GeographicLocationID = D.GeographicLocationID              

WHERE
    (D.TopRep IS NOT NULL
    AND D.RepCount IS NOT NULL
    AND D.RepResolve IS NOT NULL
    AND D.RepResolveCount IS NOT NULL
    AND D.ACSNPSPromoter IS NOT NULL
    AND D.ACSNPSDetractor IS NOT NULL
    AND D.ACSNPSCount IS NOT NULL
    AND D.AHT IS NOT NULL
    AND D.TalkTime IS NOT NULL
    AND D.CallWorkTime IS NOT NULL
    AND D.HandledCalls IS NOT NULL
    AND D.HandledCalls <> '0' )


GROUP BY
        D.DateFull,
      --Date,
      --[Month],    
      D.AreaID,               
      --GE.GeographicLocationDescription,           
      D.EmployeeID,
      nE.EmployeeName,
    D.PeopleSoftTitleStartDate,
      D.TopRep,
      D.RepCount,
      D.ERP,
      D.RepResolve,
      D.RepResolveCount,
      D.RR,
      D.ACSNPSPromoter,
      D.ACSNPSDetractor,
      D.ACSNPSCount,
      D.NPS,
      D.AHT,
      D.TalkTime,
      D.CallWorkTime,
      D.HandledCalls

ORDER BY 
      D.DateFull ASC,
      AreaID,                   
 --     Center,           
      EmployeeName    

DROP TABLE #DATA

/*Additional Info
Tech Depts - PeopleSoftDepartmentID IN ('9030', '9080', '9355', '9040', '<<OSCCALTECH>>', '<<WDTSMO>>', '9195','<<OSVTS>>', '<<OSVTS_TCS>>')
Bilingual Tech - PeopleSoftDepartmentID = '9085'
*/
```

Comment: ... When you're doing a `GROUP BY` with more than about 3-4 columns, you're probably doing something wrong (column set not unique).  If you're checking more than 2-3 'derived' ('inherited') columns for null, you need to change how you deal with them earlier.

Comment: But...all of my columns are different.  Are you saying I should select fewer columns?  I need the columns that I am selecting...I just need the info to be summarized by day rather than date range.

Comment: Well, could you provide us your table layouts, with sample data and desired results?  That sort of information would allow us to help you better.  Keep the query you currently have, and tell us how it's deficient.  At minimum, you're going to want to use a 'Calendar' table, physical (some additional columns are insanely useful) or virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> output a row of performance results for each day

One row of output per day implies `group by [Date]`.  Other columns in the `group by` clause will, well, cause the server to group by them, too, probably creating more than one row/day.  My guess, though, glancing at your query, is that you're interested in one row per day *for each employee* (you said "rep").  In that case you'd want to `group by` employee, too.

If you want other non-aggregate columns in the results, join them in later.  Here's a sketch:

```
select A.*, E.name, ... E.col_N
from ( 
  select [Date], EmployeeID, max(foo) as x, sum(bar) as y, avg(zowie) as z
  from tablename 
  group by [Date], EmployeeID
) as A
join Employees as E
on A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
```

Comment: That's the explanation I needed.  Still a bit of a newb when it comes to certain concepts here, James.  Thanks for taking the time to break it down.  I will try this out tonight.